# Degrade windows instance type from i3en to m3 without loss data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i want to degrade instance type of windows EC2 degrade from i3 to m3 can any one help me on this. which have already in running state.

Answer (score -1):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk allows you to change the instance type in the Console. Follow these steps to change the instance type.

1. Go to Elastic Beanstalk in your AWS Console
2. Select the Application that you want to change.
3. After selecting the application, select "Configuration" on the left side.
4. Click on Modify next to the "Capacity" section.
5. Scroll to "Instance type" and select your new desired instance type.
6. Click on Apply.
7. Confirm your selection in the next screen.
8. Elastic Beanstalk will start making the changes to your environment.